# Change order of changed line of a commit

Tags: git

I heard that git manages differences of a file, not a whole file, to make a repository smaller. `git diff` shows the line additions and deletions for a commit (or even for multiple commits). Also, git can apply a `*.patch` file.

But here: How can I reorder changed lines of a commit differences? For example, suppose that I changed a file

```java
a = new A() {
  @Override
  method1() {
    do_something();
  }
};
b = new B() {
  @Override
  method2() {
    do_whatever();
  }
};
c = new C() {
  @Override
  method3() {
    do_nothing();
  }
};
```

to

```java
c = new C() {
  @Override
  method3() {
    do_nothing();
  }
};
b = new B() {
  @Override
  method2() {
    do_whatever();
  }
};
a = new A() {
  @Override
  method1() {
    do_something();
  }
};
```

which is just reordering three assignments.

For this commit, `git diff` shows

```
diff --git a/a b/a
index cd702e1..7baebbe 100644
--- a/a
+++ b/a
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
-a = new A() {
+c = new C() {
   @Override
-  method1() {
-    do_something();
+  method3() {
+    do_nothing();
   }
 };
 b = new B() {
@@ -10,9 +10,9 @@ b = new B() {
     do_whatever();
   }
 };
-c = new C() {
+a = new A() {
   @Override
-  method3() {
-    do_nothing();
+  method1() {
+    do_something();
   }
 };
```

which is not logical since `@Override` keyword does not move appropriately.

I want to get something like:

```
-a = new A() {
-  @Override
-  method1() {
-    do_something();
-  }
-};
+c = new C() {
+  @Override
+  method3() {
+    do_nothing();
+  }
+};
 b = new B() {
   @Override
   method2() {
     do_whatever();
   }
 };
-c = new C() {
-  @Override
-  method3() {
-    do_nothing();
-  }
-};
+a = new A() {
+  @Override
+  method1() {
+    do_something();
+  }
+};
```

But when I made a patch file and reorder lines of it and apply it as a commit, that commit also have same `git diff` to the previous one (`@Override` not moved).

For commits including complicated line changes, default policy of `git diff` can not reflect the meaning of changes. (It would make a difficulty for peer-review.) Also, (although this is an opinion,) conflicts would be happen when changes of lines are not managed as well as I meant.

How can I change order of changed line of a commit

Comment: why would git do that if it's the same line?

Comment: Git diff has no concept of "moved lines", it simply tells you "you removed these" and "you added these", sometimes together if you changed something. As such, in your case it doesn't consider the surrounding lines to be part of the change as they weren't changed. Also, be aware that "git diff" is simply used to *explain* to you what the difference is, git stores the snapshot of those files internally and thus the diff is simply output, it isn't stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I heard that git manages differences of a file, not a whole file, to make a repository smaller.

This is incorrect. Git stores file contents as snapshots (whole file), not as deltas or diffs. Diffs such as the one you pasted in your question are calculated on demand when they are asked for.

Git supports various diff algorithms, and you can choose which one to use. One option is the *patience* algorithm. It does not produce exactly the diff you want, but it is closer to that than the default algorithm is. Here is an example:

```
diff --git a/a b/a
index cd702e1..7baebbe 100644
--- a/a
+++ b/a
@@ -1,18 +1,18 @@
-a = new A() {
-  @Override
-  method1() {
-    do_something();
-  }
-};
-b = new B() {
-  @Override
-  method2() {
-    do_whatever();
-  }
-};
 c = new C() {
   @Override
   method3() {
     do_nothing();
   }
 };
+b = new B() {
+  @Override
+  method2() {
+    do_whatever();
+  }
+};
+a = new A() {
+  @Override
+  method1() {
+    do_something();
+  }
+};
```

You can specify the algorithm using the `--diff-algorithm` option.

```
git diff --diff-algorithm=patience
```

The available algorithms are listed in [git-diff(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), and I'll quote from it here:

```
--diff-algorithm={patience|minimal|histogram|myers}
    Choose a diff algorithm. The variants are as follows:

    default, myers
        The basic greedy diff algorithm. Currently, this is the
        default.

    minimal
        Spend extra time to make sure the smallest possible diff is
        produced.

    patience
        Use "patience diff" algorithm when generating patches.

    histogram
        This algorithm extends the patience algorithm to "support
        low-occurrence common elements".

    For instance, if you configured diff.algorithm variable to a
    non-default value and want to use the default one, then you have to
    use --diff-algorithm=default option.
```